# Which version of perl was a perl script written for?

Tags: perl

I am checking an existing perl script for vulnerabilities. Most perl-related vulnerabilities only apply to certain versions. Is there a way to determine which version was used to write the perl script? (I cannot ask the developer.) Thank you!

Comment: Unless it's documented it's anyone's guess. Since you've given zero source code for context this question will likely be closed as off-topic. I don't know why you're worried about vulnerabilities. Use the latest version of Perl. If that doesn't work, find someone who can fix the code. Perl usually avoids making substantial breaking changes so backwards compatibility with older versions is often great.

Comment: The code is restricted, so I cannot publish it. I am worried about vulnerabilities because I am responsible for software assurance. I need to know the version because most CVEs apply to certain versions.

Comment: If this is of critical importance to you, sounds like you need to hire a security expert to review the code and make recommendations. Out-sourcing this to Stack Overflow is not the best way to do it. Perl itself is far less likely to be a liability than the code written for it, *especially* if you've lost contact with the original developer(s).

Comment: There's no "version" for Perl code. Most require versions of *at least X* in order to make use of particular features, but you don't see code that requires *exactly version X*. Get the latest, 5.28.0, and try your code out. If it breaks find out why.

Comment: "Most perl-related vulnerabilities only apply to certain versions". No, most vulnerabilities/bugs/issues comes from the program itself in my experience, the way it's writted, and to a lesser extent from outdated Perl-versions. Given that, separating between major versions like 4, 5 and 6 don't require much knowledge about Perl, separating between say 5.22 and 5.24 require deeper knowledge. Unless the source code have plain giveaways like `use v5.22;` or `use v6;` somewhere. Most perl code out there are version 5. Look at https://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html and the changes documents.

Comment: There's [Perl::MinimumVersion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::MinimumVersion)

Comment: Kjetil....I'm looking at CVEs to get a list of known vulnerabilities for perl. Most say something like, "Heap-based buffer overflow in the Perl_repeatcpy function in util.c in Perl 5.12.x before 5.12.5..." If I can identify the version of my perl code, then I can rule out vulnerabilities that do not apply to my version.

Comment: ikegami....thank you, that will help.

Comment: You need to determine which version(s) of perl are installed on your system(s).

Comment: *"If I can identify the version of my perl code, then I can rule out vulnerabilities that do not apply to my version"* It has already been said that Perl code doesn't have a "version": it's not like Python where a program written for Python 2 is unlikely to run under Python 3. The safest approach is to run it using the most recent Perl available; it is extremely unlikely that there will be problems. I don't see any point in picking an arbitrary release of Perl before the current one, unless you really don't want to update your installed interpreter.

Comment: All I have is the piece of code. I do not know anything about the OS, perl version, or any other (useful) information. This is not at all uncommon in software assurance. Yes, I wish I had all that information, but, alas, I do not. (I was assigned this code because I once used perl many, many years ago, which made me the perl SME on the team.) :-) Thank you all for the ideas and the education.

Comment: @lac: Please be assured that the version of perl that the code was written for is *irrelevant* except insofar as it may need a feature that was introduced later on to run at all. Suppose you found that a program was "written for" perl v5.10 but was currently being executed by perl v5.24. Surely you can see that the value `v5.10` would be of no use to you whatsoever and is completely irrelevant?

Comment: @lac Looking at the CVEs for old perl interpreters (without knowing which version) is like looking up CVEs of different C compilers to find vulnerabilities in a C program (without knowing which compiler is used). This is not _completely_ pointless, but still _largely_ so. In either case, these vulnerabilities are not in the source code which you are reviewing, but possibly in the deployed software system (which you have no information about).

Answer (score 5):

There can be some indications as to the minimum Perl version that a given script is targeting. For example:

- When an explicit version requirement is declared, e.g. `use v5.12`.
- When explicit features are used, e.g. `use feature 'say'`. See `perldoc feature` for the relationship between Perl versions and available features.
- When particular syntax is used. For example:

  - the `//` defined-or operator makes it easy notice post-5.10 code.
  - `push` or `pop` with a scalar argument signify 5.14 to 5.24.
  - Regex syntax also tends to have occasional changes, like `/d`, `/u`, `/a`, `/l` modifiers in 5.14 or `/n` in 5.22.

  You will have to read the perldelta documents for the list of relevant changes.

The Perl::MinimumVersion module can help with automating some of those checks.

However, the presence or absence of such features has *nothing* to do with the vulnerabilities of the given program. Instead:

- Make sure that you are *running* the script with an up to date Perl interpreter. Do not keep running unsupported old versions.

  Except for rare edge cases, new Perl versions are extremely backwards compatible and should work without any issue.  But note that upgrading Perl involves reinstalling all modules (in particular, any XS modules *must* be recompiled).
- Make sure you are also looking at the dependencies of the script. Are they also up to date? Whether new versions are similarly compatible will depend on the specific module.